# Email Forwarding Blacklist

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

My company sends a huge amount of spam to our work gmail accounts in the form of system emails and bureaucratic emails.

I want to only forward emails to my personal email if they **don't** match an email address on my blacklist. However, I sometimes need the system emails so I can't wholesale mark the emails as spam.

Up to this point, I have used a filter to only forward emails not on my blacklist. But now gmail is saying the blacklist is too long for the filter. If I split it into two filters, each with half of the blacklist, each filter will forward the emails from the other half of the blacklist.

What do I do?